# Table cannot be build in this way?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2017

This doesn't work for some reason. Any help will be appreciated.

```
declare @tsql varchar(100)
set @tsql = 'SELECT * INTO #TMPTABLE FROM ' + @tablename
exec(@tsql) 
set @tsql = 'drop table #TMPTABLE'
exec(@tsql)
```

> Cannot drop the table '#TMPTABLE', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

But this works:

```
 Select * INTO #TMPTABLE FROM EXAMPLETABLE
 set @tsql = 'drop table #TMPTABLE'
 exec(@tsql)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all about scope. When you use dynamic SQL you are creating new context. Local temporary table lives only inside its session(no longer).

Both scenarios below:

[image]